# Is it possible to add a password to moving or copying specific files on Linux?

Tags: security, password, directory-structure, cd-command, mv

I have a directory setup very nicely(i.e organized with READMEs and easy navigation etc.). I would like people to be able to access the files in this directory maybe even copy them to their own directory (on the same computer) but I don't want my own directory to get shaken up/messed up or else everything could get ruined. Is there anyway to put a lock on certain commands within my directory, or is there anyway of putting a lock on certain files?

For example somebody should be able to move through the space freely like this:

```
$ cd ThisDirectory
$ cd ThatDirectory
```

But they shouldn't be able to move these files like this:

```
$ mv ThisDirectory
$ mv ThatDirectory
```

Is there anyway to put a lock on the mv command for specific files?

Comment: Just don't give others write permissions to them?

Answer (score 4):

Simply change permissions of the files in a way everyone could read them, but not alter them.

When you use `ls -l` to list your files, you get something like

```
    ls -l file
    -rw-rwxr--    1 rafael   Grp      1620 Aug 18 14:58 file
```

That first set of dashes/letters sets the permitting of three distinct (but not exclude each other) groups, namely **User** (you), **Group**, **Others** (or everyone in this machine/server).

So the example above may be read as

```
    -            It's a file
     rw-         Owner may read and write
        rwx      Others in group may read, write and execute
           r--   Other users (not in group) may read
```

To prevent anyone from changing your files set them with

```
    chmod go-w file
```

This will set them to be not writable by anyone besides you

```
    ls -l file
    -rw-r-xr--    1 rafael   Grp      1620 Aug 18 14:58 file
```

Let me dive into these dash/letters:

```
    -rw-rwxr--    1 rafael   Grp      1620 Aug 18 14:58 file
```

The first one indicates the file type (directory, symlink, named pipes).  Then there are three sets of three symbols, each set is composed of one **r** (for *read*), one **w** (for *write*), and one **x** (for *e**x**ecute*), or their positions filled by a dash, if that permission is disabled.

Your directories should have the same permissions, with the addition of "execute" for all users ("executing" a directory means accessing any entry within it).  If your directories are writable, the entries in it may be deleted or renamed.

In the command `chmod`, there are three parts as well **go** (means group and others), the '-' (minus sign) is to remove (permission) and them came the (list of) rights to change

So

```
    chmod u-wx file    # prevent you reading the file or executing it
    chmod u+wx file    # permit you to read nte file or execute it
    chmod ug+rx file   # permit you and your group to read or execute it
    chmod ugo-rwx file # permit no access, for anybody
```

One last note

`chmod` also supports `-R`, for recursion, so if you have a directory called myDir:

```
    chmod -R go-w myDir  # protect everything in that directory and its sub directories/files
    chmod -R go+rX myDir # grant reading access in that directory and its sub directories/files
```

Should do the trick.

Thanks for asking, and I hope it could help others as well!

Comment: Oh, thanks @Toby Speight, for your great edits.